# Significance of different browserdriver in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

What is the significance of having different browser driver in selenium web driver like Firefox etc.although we can create web driver object and would have passed browser name as parameter name?I could not understand logic behind this..Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question...are you asking why there is a FirefoxDriver and a ChromeDriver, and a...(fill in the driver)?  This is because websites can be different based on the browser, and therefore, you should test them with different browsers.

Comment: I do  understand that site UI can launch differently on different browsers.But like RC we can pass browser name as a parameter.My question is why we have different drivers for different browsers?i know little bit funny but its question :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are multiple reasons for this

- most of the drivers are developed by 3rd party so it's makes sense to provide an interface in the API (`WebDriver`) and let the 3rd parties implement it
- it's a common Java practise to do it this way
- it's very important to avoid [Magic strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string) in code design, so they would have to use enums which would have to change with every new `WebDriver` implementation
- I guess implementation of every driver is quite different so it makes sense to provide separate class for each as an entry point